# MFC - Adding event handler for dialog button

Tags: events, button, mfc, dialog

I have a CView class and a dialog in it, and I want to get some data from the dialog object once the user clicks on its "Accept" button, so I have added an event for the button and its handler in the CView class, all done through Visual Studio 2010 menus, so I haven't screwed up the code.

CView clas:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSurface3DView, CView)
  ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_RANGE_OK, &CSurface3DView::OnBnClickedRangeOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()   
...
void CSurface3DView::OnBnClickedRangeOk()
{
 //things i need to do

}
```

The thing is, it doesn't call the OnBnClickedRangeOk() function when I the OK button is clicked.

I could also call a function from CView class from the Dialog class, but I can't use an instance for the parent class because I would need to include its header and that causes a circular inclusion, which can be solved by declaring the CView class in the Dialog header without including it, but then its methods can't be accesed.

Maybe it's not possible to put the message handle for the dialog button outside the dialog class? How do I run a certain function in the CView class only when the Dialog button is pressed?

EDIT:

Well it's solved now, I used SendMessage(hWnd, MESSAGE ,...) method of CDialog to send a message to the parent which pointer I get in the constructor of CDialog, so I don't have to declare the specific Class of the parent and I don't get inclusion problems.

The specifics to do that I found here: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?385590-How-to-SendMessage-from-child-window-to-parent

Comment: Well it's solved now, I used SendMessage(hWnd, MESSAGE ,...) method of CDialog to send a message to the parent which pointer I get in the constructor of CDialog, so I don't have to declare the specific Class of the parent and I don't get inclusion problems

Comment: Please don't put your answer in the question, write it as an answer and accept it.